# How to uninstall material-ui and install the latest MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modern-ui

My React APP currently has the old material-ui install.

How to uninstall it and install the latest MUI?

EDITED:

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "object-hash": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.38.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.3",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: `npm uninstall`/`npm install` ?

Comment: I am having trouble with the precise package names

Comment: You need to post your **package.json** then.

Comment: Just do `npm uninstall @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons` and do `npm install @mui/material`

Answer (score 3):

This is how you remove packages from your dependencies in project.json

```
npm uninstall --save <package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI has changed its package names in v5. In your scenario, you are migrating from v4 to v5. You can follow the [Material UI migration from v4 to v5 here](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/).

Basically you should install the new `@mui` packages , update your application code as needed and then you can remove old `@material-ui` packages.

Following that guide you should do some changes or update some components depending on your application.